# In cosmology, what means the 'Fourier modes'?

Tags: cosmology, universe, fourier-transform

I am reading papers of cosmology for my thesis and always I read 'Fourier modes' but I don't understand why is necessary that we work in the Fourier space and what means 'Fourier modes'? Maybe it is a way of discretizing the space for we can locate easier the positions of any 'objetc' like particles in a simulation.

Here an phrase of a paper: 
"The usual way to generate a Gaussian random field in realizations of cosmological perturbations is to generate first a set of independent Fourier modes in a three-dimensional cubic box with a specified power spectrum, and then doing the Fourier transform to obtain the real-space field. This method yields the value of the field at all the cells in the cubic volume at once."

Comment: Did you study Fourier analysis? It finds periodicity in some input data, that's why we work in Fourier space. A mode is one particular wavelength.

Comment: If you're studying a subject from the beginning I'd recommend reading a book, not papers.